# show custom plugin menu for custom user role user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am creating new user role  "test_client" and it's working but my problem is i want to show only my custom plugin page menu in dashboard but in this code "manage_options"  is 'true' then all plugin menu showing and if "manage_options" is 'false' not showing any plugin menu..

```
$result = add_role('test_client', 'Test_client', 
    array(
    // Dashboard
    'read' => true, // true allows this capability
    'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
    'edit_pages' => true, // Allows user to edit pages
    'edit_others_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
    'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
    'manage_categories' => false, // Allows user to manage post categories
    'publish_posts' => false, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
    'manage_options' => true,
    )
    );
```

so how to showing only custom plugin menu in wordpress dashboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**add custom capabilities to your plugin menu**

```
$result = add_role('test_client', 'Test_client', 
    array(
    // Dashboard
    'read' => true, // True allows this capability
    'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
    'edit_pages' => true, // Allows user to edit pages
    'edit_others_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
    'create_posts' => false, // Allows user to create new posts
    'manage_categories' => false, // Allows user to manage post categories
    'publish_posts' => false, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
    'manage_options' => false,
'custom_capability_name'=>true,
    )
    );
```

**after that add**

```
$role= get_role('test_client');
$role->add_cap('custom_capability_name');
```

finally change in your admin menu 'manage_option' to your 'cusotom_capability_name'

Comment: if i change mangae_option capability than it not showing in administrator role

Comment: you can check your role using wordpress roles function and given access to which role access or not your menu